# Ambiguous summary and end result of Review of Suggested edit

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I had a strange situation after reviewing a suggested edit yesterday where i was suspended for 2 days.

**NOTE**: This is not an appeal for the suspension, it was justified, i am trying to interpret review summary.

Here is the review url: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30777481

In the summary you can see this:

[image]

**Reject** vote is justified since the changes made by the editor don't improve the post. And my review was suppose to go under **Reject and edit**.

What confuses me is that Community **Bot** approved this edit along with another reviewer and it lead to edit being approved at the end along with [my **Improved edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70645974/revisions) where i did some code formatting. There was one rejection by a reviewer.

Is this normal behaviour where Community Bot democratically choses best voted review decision?

The end result is a bit ambiguous since it approved the bad edit along with my edit and at the same time sent a suspension action. In this case the bad edit slipped through the cracks.

**Another path it should have taken**:
Maybe the end result should have been to reject both bad edit and mine and sent a suspension action.

Comment: Before anyone mentions it, my review comment was purposeful to match the style of writing of the suggestion comment: *"Grammar was not good I fixed"*. The edit was IMO, no improvement.

Comment: Yep, that edit did not improve anything, you are correct

Comment: I think the issue here is, Community Bot didn't approve it, _you_ approved it, when you clicked "Improve edit" (community bot's name is just put beside the approval action). If you intended to click Reject and Edit, you're mistaken, you did not. For reference, this is what it shows if you click Reject and Edit:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKRe9.png

Comment: I did not click Reject and Edit, i should have done that, but the end action where bad edit and my edit slipped by and ended up in the post is what was my point.

Comment: I guess that majority approved and than Community bot approved. I think that is the case. That Community bot vote is like a stamp of approval for the decision.

Comment: Community bot simply _owns_ the action you take if you approve+edit, or reject+edit. Both of those actions are unilateral. You can be the sole reviewer and complete a review by choosing one of those actions. It's not a majority thing, you are (by picking one of those options) effectively ending the review, and the action you take is the action that holds, regardless of what other people chose.

Comment: @Ivar Trust animuson to put it into words better than I ever could :sigh:

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Ivar and Nick for your comments. I did not know the Community Bot action on these to review options. This clears a lot. 
The remaining point where bad edit slipped by is the one that remains. Since the system does not have this edge case covered, i guess the best thing would be to return the text before it was edited badly and submit the edit?

Comment: @MarioPetrovic It doesn't really matter anymore, the edit wasn't really _bad_ it just wasn't an improvement. If the edit had actively been harmful, then yes, that may have been an option. Here, I think just forget about it (except maybe that stray comma, that comma that was added should probably be removed).

Comment: Yep, i agree. That comma is extra there. I will edit the post. And hopefully be done with this :) thanks again Nick, you were very helpfull

Comment: No need, I've gone and made changes, you can just carry on with whatever you were doing (I actually ended up deciding that more of the editors suggestions in that edit were bad, and changed a bit more of it).

Answer (score 4):

In a suggested edit review, when you choose either the **Improve Edit** review action or the **Reject and Edit** review action, the Community user will also attach an "Approve" or ""Reject" vote respectively. (See [this Meta Stack Exchange Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/622284) for more details on when the Community user will approve or reject edits)

You ***had to have chosen*** the **Improve Edit** review action instead of the **Reject and Edit** action, as the resulting review summary indicates that the Community user applied an "Approve" vote simultaneously with your "Edit" choice (both actions occurred at 2022-01-10 16:39:09Z) This is to say that the Community user did not "democratically choose the best voted review decision" and rather assisted you with the review choice you made.

You should have chosen **Reject and Edit** in this situation as the changes made in the suggested edit should have been discarded before you made your changes, because as [Nick pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415224/ambiguous-summary-and-end-result-of-review-of-suggested-edit#comment888955_415224), the changes actively made the grammar of the post worse or otherwise did not improve it.

I can somewhat sympathize that the Community user's behavior isn't immediately clear. Some extra description about what's happening in the review could be beneficial in the review completion panel. However, if you look at the [revision history of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70645974/revisions), it's clear that the suggested edit was applied, then your alterations were applied.

Comment: Got it, I just read the post that Ivar suggested. It is an eye opener definitely. Thanks for your answer btw, i am learning these mechanisms slowly and on mistakes lately.

Comment: Aside from my lack of knowledge what Community Bot does, the bad edit that passed by is what i was concerned the most about i guess. Maybe the subsequent edit that was done by me, should have been rejected along with the bad edit so that this would not happen. But i guess when creating a community maintained software, there are tradeoffs.

Comment: @MarioPetrovic Your edit was a good edit, we wouldn't want that rejected. If there _haven't_ been any edits between the review and the current time, then moderators and post owners can retroactively go back and approve/reject suggested edits, but as you made an edit that's not possible here. All that needs to be done is for any issues to be fixed and to move on, these things happen, lessons get learned, no harm done.

Comment: Well, *your* edit in a vacuum was fine. The only mistake that was made was that you chose "Improve Edit" instead of "Reject and Edit" which... Happens. Had you chosen "Reject and Edit," you would have not applied the suggested edit's changes before applying your own, and all we would be left with would be your code formatting changes (which were fine).

Comment: Yep got it, both legit points @Nick and Spevacus. I made bigger deal than what is was after all. Thanks for your comments. I am still getting up to speed with these sort of details and how to react on them. Cheers